# Testing a function with request call in Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am very new to node.js and Mocha. I want to test the following function:

```
querybackend = function(url,queryParams) {
    var backendData ={};
    request({url:url, qs:queryParams}, function(err, response, body) {
        if(err) { console.log(err); return; }
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        var length = data.length;
        var tmp = data[0].DataPoints[0].length;
        var in_sum =Array.apply(null, new Array(tmp)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,0);
        var timestamp = [];
        var index1;
        var index2;
        for(index1=0;index1 < length;index1++) {
            var length2=data[index1].DataPoints.length;
            for(index2=0;index2<length2;index2++) {
                in_sum[index2]= in_sum[index2] + data[index1].DataPoints[index2][1];
                timestamp[index2] = data[index1].DataPoints[index2][0];
            }
        }
        backendData.count = in_sum;
        backendData.timestamp  = timestamp;
        deferred.resolve(backendData);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

What is the correct way to test this function? This function hits a rest end-point, gets a JSON, parses it and returns an object.

This is a sample JSON which I get:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "name1",
        "DataPoints": [
            [
                1410627915,
                242221
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "name2",
        "DataPoints": [
            [
                1410627913,
                238157
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "name3",
        "DataPoints": [
            [
                1410627922,
                215045
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

Should I mock the request? How do I mock it in Mocha?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create mocks or stubs with mocha, you need to use some module. Sinon.js (http://sinonjs.org/) is a great one, pretty easy to use and nicely documented.

I think you should mock the request function to call the callback function with the answer your rest endpoint is supposed to send you.

Then, you can test if everything your function should have done has been done correctly. By the way, if you want to test if a function has been called, you can create a spy on this function with sinon.

Answer (score 0):

I find it more convenient to use [`nock`](https://github.com/nock/nock) to incercept the request and return whatever the API should return.

This way you can as well check in different test cases if the function handles error responses like 404 or 502 gracefully.

Simple Example:

```
describe( 'querybackend', function () {

    it( 'should request the passed in URL', async function () {

        // Intercept requests to https://example.org/ and reply with HTTP 200 code 
        const scope = nock( 'https://example.org' )
            .get( '/' )
            .reply( 200 );

        // Call the function we are testing
        await querybackend( 'https://example.org/' );

        // Make sure the nock scope was properly called
        scope.done();

    } );

} );
```

I would recommend reading through the nock documentation to learn how to test different requests and responses.